# How to make a class visible in another class?

Tags: java, file, class

My problem : 
In a ReadFile class, I have a 
`public  Module ReadTheFileGetTheModuleName(String fichier)` method which has to return an object from a Module Class.

In the method, I create a module from the Module Class but when I want to return it, I have an error : **module cannot be resolved to a variable**.

Here is my code:

```
public  Module ReadTheFileGetTheModuleName(String fichier){
            try{
                InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(fichier); 
                InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
                String ligne;

                while ((ligne=br.readLine())!=null){
                    if (ligne.contains("module"))
                    {
                        /*String[] st = ligne.split(ligne, ' ');
                        System.out.println("Nom = "+st[1]);*/
                        int longueur = ligne.length();
                        ligne = ligne.substring(ligne.indexOf(" "));
                        ligne = ligne.trim();
                        System.out.println(ligne);

                        //putting the name in a Module Class
                        Module module = new Module();
                        module.setName(ligne);  
                        System.out.println("nom du module : "+module.getName());
                        module.setFichier(fichier);
                        System.out.println("nom du fichier lié au module : "+module.getFichier());

                    }

                    chaine+=ligne+"\n";

                }
                return module; //Here is the line were I have an error
                br.close();

            }       
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
**
```

Do someone knows the possible mistake I have made ?

Comment: You are creating `module` inside the while loop. Create it outside the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you declare the `module` variable inside the scope of the `if` loop, inside the `while` loop. This means that the `return` statement, that is in an outer scope, has no knowledge of the declaration.

For example, this piece of code would fail:

```
int outerVariable = 5;
if (outerVariable == 5) {
    // Ok: the inner scope can access all variables declared in the outer scopes
    int innerVariable = 1 + outerVariable;
}
// Ok: the println call and outerVariable declaration are in the same scope
System.out.println(outerVariable);

// Error: The outer scope can't access a variable declared in a inner scope
System.out.println(innerVariable);
```

In order to fix your code you need to move the declaration of `module` to an outer scope, or the `return` to the inner scope. Moving to an outer scope would look like this:

```
public Module ReadTheFileGetTheModuleName(String fichier) {
    try {
        Module module = new Module();
        while (...) {
            if (...) {
                // Set the appropriate module properties
            }
        }
        // Ok: the return statement can now see the module declaration
        return module;
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
    // Error: no return statement   
}
```

Note that you will still get an error, because you have no return statement outside the try-catch block. You need to decide what you will do in this case, you may return `null` or you can move the `module` declaration out of the try-catch and return it, like this:

```
public Module ReadTheFileGetTheModuleName(String fichier) {
    Module module = new Module();
    try {
        while (...) {
            if (...) {
                // Set the appropriate module properties
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }    
    return module;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're declaring the `module` variable in a nested scope, but then trying to use it outside that scope:

```
while (...) {
    if (...) {
        Module module = ...;
    }
}
return module;
```

What would you expect to happen if the `while` or `if` conditions never evaluated to `true`? If you want to return `null` (or some other default value) in that case, that's easy - just declare it before the loop:

```
Module module = ...;
while (...) {
    if (...) {
        module = ...;
    }
}
return module;
```

Or perhaps you should *really* be moving the `return` statement inside the `if` statement:

```
while (...) {
    if (...) {
        Module module = ...;
        ...
        return module;
    }
}
// Work out what you want to do here
```

This has *nothing* to do with different classes being involved - it's *just* about scope.

Comment: Thanks you it was the solution !

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to return within your loop the moment you create your object

Then outside the loop you will have to return `null`;